# Spring Boot and OAuth2 example: redirect not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to repeat the "Spring Boot and OAuth2" example from [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).

I run the example with "gradlew bootRun".
It is working on Windows without problems, but I having an issue on Ubuntu 14.04.
When I clicked on "login" button the service doesn't perform a redirect to the authorization server (e.g. facebook), and after several minutes return with time-out.

The service's log contains the following lines:

```
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
```

I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks.

Source code of tutorial located on [github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/logout)

My source code are given below:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")

    compile("org.webjars:webjars-locator")
    compile("org.webjars:angularjs:1.4.3")
    compile("org.webjars:jquery:2.1.1")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.2.0")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

**application.yml**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 233668646673605
      clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

**SocialApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout was caused by the secure random call.

The solution for me is the following lines:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ["-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"]
}
```